# bibtex: citation for multiple papers of two more authors with the same first author surname

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

My little  example is given below:

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
    \usepackage[sort&compress,numbers]{natbib}
    \setcitestyle{super}
    \newcommand{\citea}[1]{\citeauthor{#1}~\textsuperscript{\cite{#1}}}

    \begin{document}

    For more details,
    please see \citet{efron1996bootstrap,efron2001empirical,efron2004least}.

    For more details,
    please see \citea{efron1996bootstrap,efron2001empirical,efron2004least}.

    \bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
    \nocite{*}
    \bibliography{efron}

    \end{document}
```

where the Bibliography file efron.bib is

```
    @article{efron2004least,
    title={Least angle regression},
    author={Efron, Bradley and Hastie, Trevor and Johnstone, Iain and Tibshirani, Robert},
    journal={The Annals of Statistics},
    volume={32},
    number={2},
    pages={407--499},
    year={2004},
    publisher={Institute of Mathematical Statistics}
    }

    @article{efron2001empirical,
    title={Empirical Bayes analysis of a microarray experiment},
    author={Efron, Bradley and Tibshirani, Robert and Storey, John D and Tusher, Virginia},
    journal={Journal of the American Statistical Association},
    volume={96},
    number={456},
    pages={1151--1160},
    year={2001},
    publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
    }


    @article{efron1996bootstrap,
    title={Bootstrap confidence levels for phylogenetic trees},
    author={Efron, Bradley and Halloran, Elizabeth and Holmes, Susan},
    journal={Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences},
    volume={93},
    number={23},
    pages={13429--13429},
    year={1996},
    publisher={National Acad Sciences}
    }
```

I want to show that

```
Efron et al. $^{[1–3]}$
```

while  the default **\citet{}** gives unexpected position for commas, and 
the newly-defined **\citea{}** gives

```
Efron et al., Efron et al., Efron et al. $^{[1–3]}$
```

with multiple not-compact *Efron et al.*.

If we dont want to make it through manually typing as

```
    For more details,
    please see Efron et al. \cite{efron1996bootstrap,efron2001empirical,efron2004least}.
```

what can we do by modifying **\citet** or redefining **\citea**?

Comment: Off-topic: You should encase the word `Bayes` in curly braces to keep it from getting converted to lowercase, i.e., `bayes`.

Comment: Accepted! Thanks for your suggestion! @ Mico

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{efron.bib}
@article{efron2004least,
title  ={Least angle regression},
author ={Efron, Bradley and Hastie, Trevor and Johnstone, Iain and Tibshirani, Robert},
journal={The Annals of Statistics},
volume ={32},
number ={2},
pages  ={407--499},
year   ={2004},
publisher={Institute of Mathematical Statistics},
}

@article{efron2001empirical,
title  ={Empirical {Bayes} analysis of a microarray experiment},
author ={Efron, Bradley and Tibshirani, Robert and 
        Storey, John D. and Tusher, Virginia},
journal={Journal of the American Statistical Association},
volume ={96},
number ={456},
pages  ={1151--1160},
year   ={2001},
publisher={Taylor \& Francis},
}

@article{efron1996bootstrap,
title  ={Bootstrap confidence levels for phylogenetic trees},
author ={Efron, Bradley and Halloran, Elizabeth and Holmes, Susan},
journal={Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences},
volume ={93},
number ={23},
pages  ={13429--13429},
year   ={1996},
publisher={National Acad Sciences},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sort&compress,super,square]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\newcommand\citea[2]{\citeauthor{#1}\cite{#2}}

\begin{document}
\citea{efron1996bootstrap}{efron1996bootstrap, efron2001empirical, efron2004least}.
\bibliography{efron}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is great! Thanks a lot ! @Mico