# \Citet{} With Same First Author Lists Each Paper Individually 'Author [1,2,3,4]', Instead Of As A Range 'Author [1–4]'

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

I'm citing several papers of the same author. If I use the `\cite{}` command, it states the range [1–4], but if I use the `\citet{}` command, it lists each number individually

> Author et al. [1,2,3,4].

Is there a way to print it as

> Author et al. [1–4]?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{revtex4-2}
\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-2}
\begin{document}
\citet{akarsu_graduated_2020,akarsu_lambda_rm_2023,akarsu_relaxing_2021,akarsu_relaxing_2023}
\cite{akarsu_graduated_2020,akarsu_lambda_rm_2023,akarsu_relaxing_2021,akarsu_relaxing_2023}
\bibliography{bib}
\end{document}
```

with the `bib.bib` file

```
@misc{akarsu_lambda_rm_2023,
    title = {\${\textbackslash}{Lambda}\_\{{\textbackslash}rm s\}\${CDM} model: {A} promising scenario for alleviation of cosmological tensions},
    shorttitle = {\${\textbackslash}{Lambda}\_\{{\textbackslash}rm s\}\${CDM} model},
    url = {http://arxiv.org/abs/2307.10899},
    urldate = {2024-03-06},
    publisher = {arXiv},
    author = {Akarsu, Ozgur and Di Valentino, Eleonora and Kumar, Suresh and Nunes, Rafael C. and Vazquez, J. Alberto and Yadav, Anita},
    month = jul,
    year = {2023},
    note = {arXiv:2307.10899 [astro-ph, physics:gr-qc]},
    keywords = {Astrophysics - Cosmology and Nongalactic Astrophysics, General Relativity and Quantum Cosmology, Hubble tension},
}

@article{akarsu_graduated_2020,
    title = {Graduated dark energy: {Observational} hints of a spontaneous sign switch in the cosmological constant},
    volume = {101},
    issn = {2470-0010, 2470-0029},
    shorttitle = {Graduated dark energy},
    url = {http://arxiv.org/abs/1912.08751},
    doi = {10.1103/PhysRevD.101.063528},
    number = {6},
    urldate = {2024-03-06},
    journal = {Physical Review D},
    author = {Akarsu, Ozgur and Barrow, John D. and Escamilla, Luis A. and Vazquez, J. Alberto},
    month = mar,
    year = {2020},
    note = {arXiv:1912.08751 [astro-ph, physics:gr-qc, physics:hep-ph, physics:hep-th]},
    keywords = {Astrophysics - Cosmology and Nongalactic Astrophysics, General Relativity and Quantum Cosmology, High Energy Physics - Phenomenology, High Energy Physics - Theory, Hubble tension},
    pages = {063528},
}

@article{akarsu_relaxing_2021,
    title = {Relaxing cosmological tensions with a sign switching cosmological constant},
    volume = {104},
    issn = {2470-0010, 2470-0029},
    url = {http://arxiv.org/abs/2108.09239},
    doi = {10.1103/PhysRevD.104.123512},
    number = {12},
    urldate = {2024-03-06},
    journal = {Physical Review D},
    author = {Akarsu, Ozgur and Kumar, Suresh and Ozulker, Emre and Vazquez, J. Alberto},
    month = dec,
    year = {2021},
    note = {arXiv:2108.09239 [astro-ph, physics:gr-qc]},
    keywords = {Astrophysics - Cosmology and Nongalactic Astrophysics, General Relativity and Quantum Cosmology, Hubble tension},
    pages = {123512},
}

@article{akarsu_relaxing_2023,
    title = {Relaxing cosmological tensions with a sign switching cosmological constant: {Improved} results with {Planck}, {BAO}, and {Pantheon} data},
    volume = {108},
    issn = {2470-0010, 2470-0029},
    shorttitle = {Relaxing cosmological tensions with a sign switching cosmological constant},
    url = {http://arxiv.org/abs/2211.05742},
    doi = {10.1103/PhysRevD.108.023513},
    number = {2},
    urldate = {2024-03-06},
    journal = {Physical Review D},
    author = {Akarsu, Ozgur and Kumar, Suresh and Ozulker, Emre and Vazquez, J. Alberto and Yadav, Anita},
    month = jul,
    year = {2023},
    note = {arXiv:2211.05742 [astro-ph]},
    keywords = {Astrophysics - Cosmology and Nongalactic Astrophysics, Hubble tension},
    pages = {023513},
}
```

Thank you very much for your time, and for your help in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In adaption of [Mico's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/488540/277964) to a [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/488529/bibtex-citation-for-multiple-papers-of-two-more-authors-with-the-same-first-aut), you could use:

```latex
\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@misc{akarsu_lambda_rm_2023,
    title = {\${\textbackslash}{Lambda}\_\{{\textbackslash}rm s\}\${CDM} model: {A} promising scenario for alleviation of cosmological tensions},
    shorttitle = {\${\textbackslash}{Lambda}\_\{{\textbackslash}rm s\}\${CDM} model},
    url = {http://arxiv.org/abs/2307.10899},
    urldate = {2024-03-06},
    publisher = {arXiv},
    author = {Akarsu, Ozgur and Di Valentino, Eleonora and Kumar, Suresh and Nunes, Rafael C. and Vazquez, J. Alberto and Yadav, Anita},
    month = jul,
    year = {2023},
    note = {arXiv:2307.10899 [astro-ph, physics:gr-qc]},
    keywords = {Astrophysics - Cosmology and Nongalactic Astrophysics, General Relativity and Quantum Cosmology, Hubble tension},
}

@article{akarsu_graduated_2020,
    title = {Graduated dark energy: {Observational} hints of a spontaneous sign switch in the cosmological constant},
    volume = {101},
    issn = {2470-0010, 2470-0029},
    shorttitle = {Graduated dark energy},
    url = {http://arxiv.org/abs/1912.08751},
    doi = {10.1103/PhysRevD.101.063528},
    number = {6},
    urldate = {2024-03-06},
    journal = {Physical Review D},
    author = {Akarsu, Ozgur and Barrow, John D. and Escamilla, Luis A. and Vazquez, J. Alberto},
    month = mar,
    year = {2020},
    note = {arXiv:1912.08751 [astro-ph, physics:gr-qc, physics:hep-ph, physics:hep-th]},
    keywords = {Astrophysics - Cosmology and Nongalactic Astrophysics, General Relativity and Quantum Cosmology, High Energy Physics - Phenomenology, High Energy Physics - Theory, Hubble tension},
    pages = {063528},
}

@article{akarsu_relaxing_2021,
    title = {Relaxing cosmological tensions with a sign switching cosmological constant},
    volume = {104},
    issn = {2470-0010, 2470-0029},
    url = {http://arxiv.org/abs/2108.09239},
    doi = {10.1103/PhysRevD.104.123512},
    number = {12},
    urldate = {2024-03-06},
    journal = {Physical Review D},
    author = {Akarsu, Ozgur and Kumar, Suresh and Ozulker, Emre and Vazquez, J. Alberto},
    month = dec,
    year = {2021},
    note = {arXiv:2108.09239 [astro-ph, physics:gr-qc]},
    keywords = {Astrophysics - Cosmology and Nongalactic Astrophysics, General Relativity and Quantum Cosmology, Hubble tension},
    pages = {123512},
}

@article{akarsu_relaxing_2023,
    title = {Relaxing cosmological tensions with a sign switching cosmological constant: {Improved} results with {Planck}, {BAO}, and {Pantheon} data},
    volume = {108},
    issn = {2470-0010, 2470-0029},
    shorttitle = {Relaxing cosmological tensions with a sign switching cosmological constant},
    url = {http://arxiv.org/abs/2211.05742},
    doi = {10.1103/PhysRevD.108.023513},
    number = {2},
    urldate = {2024-03-06},
    journal = {Physical Review D},
    author = {Akarsu, Ozgur and Kumar, Suresh and Ozulker, Emre and Vazquez, J. Alberto and Yadav, Anita},
    month = jul,
    year = {2023},
    note = {arXiv:2211.05742 [astro-ph]},
    keywords = {Astrophysics - Cosmology and Nongalactic Astrophysics, Hubble tension},
    pages = {023513},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{revtex4-2}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{ \citext } { O{#2} m }
  {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { , } { #1 }
    \citeauthor{ \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 1 } } \c_space_token \citep{#2}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-2}
\begin{document}
\verb|\citext|: \citext{akarsu_graduated_2020,akarsu_lambda_rm_2023,akarsu_relaxing_2021,akarsu_relaxing_2023}

\verb|\citet|: \citet{akarsu_graduated_2020,akarsu_lambda_rm_2023,akarsu_relaxing_2021,akarsu_relaxing_2023}

\verb|\citep|: \citep{akarsu_graduated_2020,akarsu_lambda_rm_2023,akarsu_relaxing_2021,akarsu_relaxing_2023}

\verb|\cite|: \cite{akarsu_graduated_2020,akarsu_lambda_rm_2023,akarsu_relaxing_2021,akarsu_relaxing_2023}
\bibliography{bib}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But note: Only the author of the first entry in the list is shown. So if the cites are from different authors, you should not use `\citext`.